# Disable animation in the window switcher?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

Recently `alt+tab` started using animations on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04). I did not change any settings. How can I disable this animation?

Answer (score 4):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

will disable animations in gnome.

Comment: This would disable all animations in gnome. Can we disable most animations but the activities shell animations, which I find neat? I'm only annoyed by the animations during `alt+tab` and workspace switching...